# Finding the splitting field of $x^4+x^2-6$ over $\mathbb{Z_7}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{13}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, splitting-field

Finding the splitting field of $x^4+x^2-6$ over $\mathbb{Z_7}$ and $\mathbb{Z_{13}}$.

So should I start off by just checking for roots? Or should I let $\alpha$ be a root and see if I need to add anything else after I add that? Either way, I'd appreciate it if anyone could lend some insight into the best ways to approach problems like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

$$x^4+x^2-6=(x^2+3)(x^2-2)$$

Now, is it possible to find square root to $\;-3\;$ in $\;\Bbb F_p\;,\;\;p=7,\,13\;$ ? What about square root of $\;2\;$ ....?

Once you have the above, check for possible quadratic extensions

**Added under request**: since (Legendre's Symbol):

$$\begin{pmatrix}-3\\7\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\7\end{pmatrix}=1$$

$\;-3\;$ is a square $\;\pmod 7\;$ , and in fact $\;x^2+3=(x-2)(x-5)\pmod7\;$ , and since also $\;(\pm3)^2=2\pmod 7\;$ , we get $\;x^2-2=(x-3)(x+3)\pmod7\;$ , so in fact

$$x^4+x^2-7=(x-2)(x-5)(x-3)(x+3)\pmod 7$$

so the quartic completey splits in $\;\Bbb F_7\;$ and this last is the splitting field of it (over $\;\Bbb F_7\;$) .

Over $\;\Bbb F_{11}\;$ . Since neither $\;-3\;$ nor $\;2\;$ are squares $\;\pmod{11}\;$ (check this!), we need a quadratic extension to add a root $\;w\;$ of $\;x^2+3\;$ to $\;\Bbb F_{11}\;$ :

$$K:=\Bbb F_{11}/\langle x^2+3\rangle\cong\Bbb F_{11}(w)$$ .

Knowing that there is one single extension (up to isomorphism) of any given degree for any finite field, show that $\;x^2-2\;$ also splits over $\;K\;$ . Fill in details.

Comment: When you say check for quadratic extensions, you mean that if there are no roots in the respective fields, then just let $\alpha$ be a root and see if you get the other root? Which you will I believe since the irreducible factors are of degree 2.

Comment: @MichaelVaughan Also, extending a finite field by adjoining a square root is a bit different from extending the rationals. When you adjoin one missing square root to a finite field you get *all the others* free of charge! That's because a finite field has only a single quadratic extension. If you haven't seen that result, then there is also a more elementary way of seeing the same thing.

Comment: Wow, adding one square root and you get all the square roots!? Finite fields have a single quadratic extension!!!!??? I didn't know these things, have any favorite proofs that you could link me to?

Comment: Can someone finish DonAntonios work. As I understand $Z_7$ is a spiltting field for the given polyinomial. But $Z_{13}$ is not since $2$ is not a square root in $Z_{13}$. So the splitting field is $Z_{13}[\sqrt{2}]$? Is that any concrete field? I mean standard-well known field?